# JavaScript run code before a function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

How can I execute some javascript before running a function? I have tried doing something like this:

```
Function.prototype._call= Function.prototype.call;
Function.prototype.call = function(src) {
    console.log('A function was called name = ', src)
    Function.prototype._call(src);
}
```

But that only works when I use

```
myfunction.call()
```

And I want the code to work when I call any function normally eg:

```
myfunction()
```

Comment: you must try to use [promises](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises). this could ensure the order of async actions

Comment: If your code really did what you are intending, you would have an infinite loop because `console.log` would trigger it and cause infinite recursion. What you are attempting is (rightly) not possible.

Comment: @lonesomeday cant you add if (Function.prototype.caller != 'console')

Comment: You can, but be aware that it is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Comment: Why override `.call` on _every single function_? That sounds like a recipe for disaster and for subtle bugs you never realise about until too late. Why not just have a higher order function that returns a new one that can have whatever you want before/after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such API in JavaScript. The closest thing is ECMAScript 2015's Proxy objects that provides ["Meta Programming"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Meta_programming) features. The `apply` trap handler is called for function invocations:

```
var proxy = new Proxy(function functionName() { /* ... */ }, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
     console.log('%s was called', target.name);
     // you may want to use the `Function.prototype.apply` 
     // instead of the `()` operator
     target();
  }
});

proxy();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing built-in JavaScript. That's just something you have to implement yourself:

```
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  this.beforeEach = function() {
    //runs before each method
  }

  this.myFunction = function() {
    self.beforeEach();
    //function code
  }

  this.myOtherFunction = function() {
    self.beforeEach();
    //function code
  }

}
```

Not elegant, but it works.